# Properly embed Google Apps Script URL into Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, google-sites

In Google Sites, it is possible to embed a Google Apps Script which has been published as a Web App. You just click "embed" and paste the URL of the Web App. It is possible to use the mouse to resize the iframe. However, I could not set the iframe to be of full width. Is that possible? Also, is it possible to make the whole page scrollable (instead of the iframe) when the Web App has some larger height as well? (I actually don't want to use any other functionalities of Google Sites except that it "hosts" my Google Apps Script with a custom URL and that it gets rid of the standard header warning that this Web App is not by Google).

Comment: Interesting question. On first look, There doesn't seem to be any way to resize the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sorry

Unfortunately, AFAIK, **this is not possible within Google sites**.

I have experimented with various custom iframe HTML and CSS to try and find a workaround, but due to the way the site is rendered, it will always wrap your custom code in its own HTML and CSS. Any solution along these lines seems like it will be unreliable.

If you would like to see this specific functionality you can always submit a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui).

#### My best workaround so far

- Start a new site.
- Delete all the elements, including the title.
- Then add in your webapp embed.

It let me resize it vertically as far down as I wanted, it seems like full width since it is the only element on the page, and it doesn't present me with the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. So then I will probably move away from Google sites. They are just too restricted (also when it comes to other custom design things).

Comment: About your workaround: This is what I already do. But when the page of the webapp has a vertical scrollbar, that scrollbar will never be the one of the Google site. You always see it as an iframe.